# Is there a way to find the computational resources required to perform a simulation of n- qubits in Cirq similar to qsim?

Tags: vqe, cirq, memory-space

I’m trying to model basic spin chains in 1D using VQE (ideal circuit) with cirq and qsim. The models have between 10-20 sites and varying interactions (nearest neighbour, next to nearest neighbour etc).
I would like to create a function with which I can do a preliminary estimate of the memory allocation requirements. I found this [guide detailing the process for qsim(C++ based)](https://quantumai.google/qsim/choose_hw) useful. Does anyone know of a similar method to calculate the requirements using the native simulator in cirq (python based)?